# Kestrel return response to user and continue processing

Tags: c#, kestrel-http-server

I have an application using Kestrel and I have a rather long(8+ second) function thats gets run. At the end the client gets back a generated id.

What I would need to happen is we receive the request immediately generate the id for the client and then release the client. So in the clients mind the request is "finished" however for our application it will continue to process the request in another thread(or the same thread doesnt matter)

So heres what I have done

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {

            app
                .UseMaxConcurrentRequests()
                .Run(async (context) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
            // Generated id
                        string gid = GlobalMethods.GetUniqueKey(14);
                        
                        var url = context.Request.Path.Value;

                        /*
            Bunch of url manipulation
            */

            // Long running task that I expect calling
            // Task.Run would send it away
            // But for some reason the client still waits here till this finishes
                        Task.Run(() => Routing(segments, requestFromBody, gid));
            
            // I know this is what sends the response
            // Back to the client and I even tried
            // To put this at the very top of the method
            // But it still waits for routing to finish
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync(gid);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Logger.Instance.ErrorLogBuffer.Add($"{ex.Message}{Environment.NewLine}{Environment.NewLine}{ex.StackTrace}");
                    }
                });
        }
```

Check the code for comments on whats happening

So I have tried several different approaches like making the `Routing` method async and not calling the await

I just can't figure this one out and it is the most important thing that we respond to the client as fast as possible and release them and continue processing the request

I have commented out the routing method call and saw that responses to the client were lightning quick but no matter what if the Routing method is called it waits for it to finish

I think I should also note that I am not using a asp.net template I am using .NET 6 console application

Comment: You must send a response for the client to get released.  The responds does not have to wait for the processing to finish.  The best way is for server to send response before doing the processing.  Where in your code do you send the response?

Comment: @jdweng This line here context.Response.WriteAsync(gid);

Comment: send the response before doing processing with no grid.  You should have a second connection between client and server (UDP, Broadcast or TCP) that sends the grid when processing is finished.  There should be an ID used in http request/response to link with the grid returned in 2nd connecttion.

Comment: See following to use Task.Run() asynchronously : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-6.0.  You Routing() method may have a await which is stopping the asynchronous from working.

Answer (score 0):

The `Task.Run` should work just fine. Just make sure you copy and state from the incoming request before handing it off for processing.